# How to deal with dynamic connection strings in runtime for EF 4.1?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, connection-string, poco

I can not use config files, I have to init database connetcion in runtime. It's SQL Server 2008 database.

Since I updated EF to newer ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.1 - Update 1, Database.Connection.ConnectionString does not work for me any more. Connection string in config file works fine for me, but I need to define it dynamically. So I found other popular way to do it by DefaultConnectionFactory like this:

```
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = 
    new SqlConnectionFactory("Server=local;Initial Catalog=Db1;Trusted_Connection=True;")
```

However in the case I got the error message trying to access any DbSet derived object: *The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)*

UPDATE: I experience the issue only in the case database is not yet created and supposed to be rebuild by EF. In case it exists, no such exception occurs as I query Db for data. If I define exactly the same connection string in config files, both cases works fine for me (database generation and data query)

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: "I can not use config files" - umm....why not???

Comment: because connection string is known in runtime only, it's built dynamically based on user authenticated

Answer (score 3):

You can use  `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` class to build the connection string for the context,

```
EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder =new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
entityBuilder.Provider = "provider";
entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = "connectionString";
```

and pass when creating the dbContext

```
 YourContext(entityBuilder.ToString())
```

Comment: Database.DefaultConnectionFactory and Database.Connection.ConnectionString still do not work for me with or without this EntityConnectionStringBuilder. However it turns out the way to pass connection string into the base class is the only way works for me both for generation new Db schema and date query. Ok, I can use base class constructor to pass connection string, but I'm still curious why other 2 ways worked for me on some past EF version do not work any more with the newest EF version.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a config file the config starts with a default and you can change the value at runtime this specifically what hey are designed for and can be set to application wide or per user scope. So start with a empty config setting build your string at runtime and set it to the config file and have your application read from it I do this quite frequently.

I'll post some example code for the way I handle this tomorrow when I get to work

Comment: I have been been adding an entry to app.config at runtime, but EF doesnt seem to read it.  Any tips?